# How to clear fileInput data and corresponding objects in R Shiny?

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

After looking at some exisiting solutions I still could not solve the problem.

I want to delete every data that was uploaded in my shiny app after pressing the sign_out button (which of course also logs out the users).

**To upload data I am using the fileInput() command in Shiny.**

```
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv", "space"))
```

**The corresponding data object based on this input is called df:**

```
output$contents <- renderTable({
req(input$file1)

        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)
})
```

**My current approach to remove this is the following:**

```
  observeEvent(input$sign_out, {
    df <- NULL 
    reset(id = "") # from shinyjs package 
    f$sign_out()
    output$test <- renderTable({
      df()})
    
  })
```

The output$test object shows that after relogin the data of "df" is still there.

Hope you could help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you assigning the updated value to a local variable (df), within the observeEvent() function? This will not affect the global `df` that was created with read.csv() function and hence is getting displayed in the renderTable() function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using <<- instead of <- but it still doesn't work. Could you tell me how you would assign the NULL to the df object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I think I could solve the issue. Instead of setting any reactive Value to NULL I deleted the csv. file which is created when uploading data.

The key function for that is `unlink`.

```
  observeEvent(input$sign_out, {
    unlink(input$file1$datapath)
    reset(id = "") # from shinyjs package
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is, first, at the beginning of your code, just add this line of code:

```
values <- reactiveValues(uploadedData = NULL)
```

Secondly, you should modify the `renderTable()` function to use `values$uploadedData`  instead of `df` :

```
renderTable({
req(input$file1)

        values$uploadedData <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                             header = input$header,
                             sep = input$sep,
                             quote = input$quote)
```

And also,you must replace the line

```
output$test <- renderTable({ df() })
```

With this line of code:

```
output$test <- renderTable({ values$uploaded_data })
```

Lastly, when the user logs out, to empty the uploadedData, modify the observeEvent() by setting the values$uploadedData() to NULL :

```
observeEvent(input$sign_out, {
  values$uploadedData <- NULL 
  reset(id = "") # from shinyjs package 
  f$sign_out()
})
```

Try this, and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick respond! So I changed my code according to your suggestion and, indeed, output$test shows no data table anymore. 

Unfortunately, the output$data_table <- renderTable({...}) section still plots the data in the UI after re-login indicating that the data wasn't removed.

Also, once I log in again, I can continue to use the data for calculation without having to upload anything.

Comment: i guess, you might need to fix the codes in the rest of the App code as well.. check where else df is being used. of if you could share the app code, baring login related ones, we might be able to help further. Just see if you could include `values$uploadedData <- NULL `  in your rest of the app functions as well.